# Select box not updating the UI after remove control of reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I am using `"@angular/cli": "1.2.6"`, `"@angular/core": "^4.0.0"`

**What I want to do**
I am trying to make a reactive form of a product with feature input. Inside the form, if user click the "add feature" button, a new feature column including a select box of "type" will appear. And once the user click the "remove" button inside the feature column, that feature column will be removed.

**What problem I met**
The problem is when I try to remove a feature column in between the first and the last feature column, the formControl is successfully updated with the correct value. However, the UI of the select box of that removed feature column will pass to the next feature column upcoming.

**What I expect to have**
Once the target feature column removed, the UI of the upcoming feature column will go up with the correct value.

**Sample**
1. I try to remove the second feature column.
[image]
2. formControl successfully removed the second feature. The second feature column in UI is successfully removed. However, the third feature column goes up and replaces the space with the select box's value of the removed feature. 
[image]

my code is as follow:

**product-form.component.ts**

```
formDOM;
features = [];
featureTypes = [
  { id: "pros", name: "pros" },
  { id: "cons", name: "cons" }];

ngOnInit() {
  this.formDOM = this.formBuilder.group({
    // Have other field....
    feature: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}

patchSingleFeature(feature: object): FormGroup {
  let returnObject = this.formBuilder.group({
    type: (feature && feature['type'])
    // some other field also....
  });

  this.features.push("feature");
  return returnObject;
}

addFeature(): void {
  let featureControl = <FormArray>this.formDOM.controls['feature'];
  featureControl.push(this.patchSingleFeature(new Feature()));
}

removeFeature(x: number): void {
  let numberOfFeature = this.features.length;
  let featureControl = <FormArray>this.formDOM.controls['feature'];
  featureControl.controls.splice(x, 1);
  this.features.splice(x, 1);
}
```

**product-form.component.html**

```
<div class="form" [formGroup]="formDOM">
  <div class="col-xs-12">Features</div>
  <div *ngFor="let feature of features; let x = index; ">
    <feature-input [x]="x" [featureTypes]="featureTypes" [form]="formDOM" (clickEvent)="removeFeature($event)"></feature-input>
  </div>
  <button (click)="addFeature()">Add Feature</button>
</div>
```

**feature-input.component.html**

```
<div class="feature-input" [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="feature">
    <div [formGroupName]="x">
      <select formControlName="type">
        <option value="" disabled>-- Select Feature Type --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let type of featureTypes" [value]="type.id">{{ type.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**feature-input.component.ts**

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
@Input() featureTypes: Array<object>;
@Input() x: number;
@Output() clickEvent new EventEmitter<number>();

removeFeature(x) { this.clickEvent.emit(x); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make some changes to your code. I would send the whole formarray to the child component and iterate it there. As objects are mutable in JS, you don't need an `EventEmitter`, but you can perform the deletion in child without emitting anything to parent.

So in this case, since you don't have a nested form group, pass the whole form to child:

```html
<feature-input [featureTypes]="featureTypes"></feature-input>
```

Make the appropriate changes to the input fields, and then your child template would look like this:

```html
  <div class="feature-input" [formArray]="featureTypes">
    <div *ngFor="let ctrl of featureTypes.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <select formControlName="type">
      <option value="" disabled>-- Select Feature Type --</option>
      <option *ngFor="let type of featureTypes" [value]="type.id">{{ type.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <button (click)="removeFeature(i)">Remove</button>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

In `removeFeature` we just pass the index of the form group and use the function `removeAt`, which is available for form arrays:

```html
removeFeature(index) {
  this.formGroup.get('feature').removeAt(index)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works perfectly. May I know what's the problem of my code?

Comment: Well, you have some strange thing going on there, using a `features` array. You are deleting items from the `features` array as, not actually the formarray, so that is 'messing up it. You don't need the `features` array at all, so I don't know why you are using it :)

Comment: I got it now :P Thank you for the explanation :) After reading your answer, I just find out that the `features` is useless, haha

Answer (score 0):

You should directly use the removeAt with index on FormArray.

`(<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['items']).removeAt(index);`

If you are using splice on the form controls then you have to use updateValueAndValidity for each item then it will update the array.

`this.formControls.splice(index, 1)`

`this.formControls.map(data => {data[controls].value.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false, emitEvent: false });});`